# Blender is not on the start menu

Tags: windows

The blender shortcut says it's pinned to start as shown in the photo, [image: It's pinned]

but when actually looking through the start menu or the Windows search, it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: I think this is an issue with your operating system, not blender.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about Blender

Comment: everything else works, blender doesnt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not about blender  but about configuring the OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you can copy the blender shortcut and go hit the `WindowsKey+R` or search for `Run`. Next type `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and hit enter. Then a folder will open, just paste the shortcut into the folder and it should show up in your search bar.
Next time please ask questions as such on https://superuser.com/

Comment: it's already there, and it only did it for blender so I posted it here. next time ill post it there, thanks!

Comment: sorry for accepting this answer so late, it happened again and I found this post, so I followed these steps and it worked. I don't know why it didn't work for 2017 me.

Comment: No probs, I'm glad it worked for ya :)

Answer (score 1):

This has probably happened as you downloaded the ZIP file instead of the Installer(.msi) file. If you download the installer instead it will put the icon into the menu and you will be able to search for it.